# Sequelize findAll Query Result with Specific Attributes from Included Table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am facing an issue with Sequelize's findAll function. I have the following code:

```
const user_role = await db.user_role.findAll(
    {
        include: {
            model: db.role,
            as: 'role',
            attributes: ['slug'],
        },
        where:{
            userId:{
                [Op.eq]: userId
            }
        },
        attributes: [role.slug],
        raw: true
    }
);
```

However, the result I'm getting includes all the attributes from the included table along with the desired attribute. For example:

```
[
  { slug: 'admin', 'role.slug': 'admin' },
  { slug: 'buyer', 'role.slug': 'buyer' }
]
```

But what I actually want is:

```
[
  { slug: 'admin' },
  { slug: 'buyer' }
]
```

Is there any attribute or setting in Sequelize that can achieve this? I'd prefer not to use .map to filter the results. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the `subQuery: false` option to the `findAll` query. This option prevents Sequelize from creating subqueries for each included table, allowing me to get only the desired attributes from the included table.

```
const user_role = await db.user_role.findAll(
{
    include: {
        model: db.role,
        as: 'role',
        attributes: [],
    },
    where:{
        userId:{
            [Op.eq]: userId
        }
    },
    attributes: ['role.slug'],
    raw: true,
    subQuery: false  // This line prevents Sequelize from creating subqueries
});
```